# Best practice to integrate web services (with Camel)

Tags: web-services, jms, integration, apache-camel

I have the following situation. Several services provide their functionality mainly via SOAP interfaces. There is one module that wants to consume this functionality for integration into a website. What would be the best practice to do that?

The functionality of the services is subject to change. Therefore, each single function/method should be "reroutable". The web service is probably hosted on a different machine.

Is it reasonable to map all web services to JMS queues (my first idea)? The website module would only talk to JMS then. A router would route all incoming JMS messages to the different web services (or elsewhere).

Or: There could be one dedicated web service, that integrates all functions, to be used exclusively by the web site? The advantage here would be that parameters and return values are typed.

What would you suggest? What could be another, better approach?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right, what you're aiming at is providing a homogeneous interface, a coherent API for your webapp module, serving a purpose of a facade for multiple remote interfaces (mainly SOAP ones).

Regarding the JMS approach you've mentioned - it seems reasonable, but:

- instead of many queues I'd rather go with a single JMS destination with a Camel content-based router immediately after the queue (or two queues for Request/Reply pattern) That would make things "reroutable" and isolate the web module from service changes.
- your requests would be less prone to services-related errors, brief problems in service availability and such, while still retaining an ability to perform Request/Reply style calls (which are common to RPC-ish nature of SOAP).
- i'd use one-way style calls wherever they are applicable (for increased reliability and reactivity).
- You should not worry about lack of typing, WSDL+SOAP seems to enforce strong typing but that's an illusion driven by auto-generated stubs. You still have to marshal the data back and forth. 
  Instead of SOAP I'd go with JSON, as it is far cleaner and less redundant than XML (probably faster, but that's usually irrelevant). **Jackson** is a very efficient JSON library and it's already supported in Camel distributions. JMS `ObjectMessage` is a big **NO** ([a good article on some of the `ObjectMessage` pitfalls](http://www.jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/) )

The single-service approach seems to be a good way to separate the web-module from the service layer. It lacks the flexibility and fault-tolerance of the JMS approach but seems tad easier to implement.

If there are many calls that can be concluded in a one-way fashion, I'd say go with JMS and reroute the messages after the queue.